# Globally reserving a CPU register

Tags: c

I am writing a VM, and I need one CPU register for my own use globally, in other words I need to tell the C compiler not to use this register in any way. And probably the compiler must preserve this register when calling third party libraries (when there is no guarantees about the register user). Is this possible, if yes, how?
Does not matter if it's Clang or GCC or something else, I will choose the compiler that can do this.

Comment: I highly doubt there's a portable (across CPUs) way to do this. Also, you must convince the Operating System, not the compiler.

Comment: Which register? Depending on platform, the usage of (some) registers is regulated by ABI, and you can't change that.

Comment: Yes, you can customise the ABI definitions in GCC then build your own compiler. I expect it's easy enough in Clang too.

Comment: @Rup ..and build all of the libraries the program might be using with that compiler. And of course there is no point in either of these if this thing is supposed to run under some common OS not built by the same compiler.

Comment: @EugeneSh. not sure I understand your point, isn't it easy to just spill the register when calling to the third party libraries using `push`/`pop`?

Comment: @exebook Do you want the register not to be used at all, or you want to guarantee it's value preserved during execution of specific blocks of code?

Comment: @EugeneSh. what was on my mind is to store something in the register that is used basically in every VM instruction, theoretically this could speed up the VM pretty much.